# WebSocket connection to website failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: firebase, websocket, firebase-hosting

I just deployed a quick test (a simple 'Hello world' with reactJS) to Firebase. (I just made a new Firebase project and deployed my code so I didn't configure anything in the Firebase dashboard.) In the browser console I saw some errors due to webSocket. Can someone help me out by telling how I can check were these requests are coming from?

This is my console screen with the errors.

[image]

And the requests. They
[image]

Website: https://test-1d6f7.firebaseapp.com/

EDIT: code

script.js

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import router from './router/';

const init = () => {
  render(
    router,
    document.querySelector(`.react-app`)
  );
};

init();
```

Router/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {App} from './../containers/';

export default (
  <BrowserRouter >
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        {this.props.children}
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Nothing in Firebase Hosting automatically connects a web socket when a user accesses your site. The URL pattern also doesn't look like it's coming from the Firebase Database client. I'm not sure where the connection is coming from in your case.

Comment: Just checked Firebase Hosting but found nothing. Any suggestion what I can do next?

Answer (score 1):

[Update] I found out that the problem started when I added

```
"rewrites": [{"source": "**", "destination": "/index.html"}]
```

to my firebase.json file.

I'm using this line to be able to go to specific urls on my website without getting an 404. ([see this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/thore%7Csort:relevance/firebase-talk/37IKxuAJJsw/QUGqgdYBBQAJ))

Answer (score 0):

The error is connecting to:

> 'wss://test-1d6f7.firebaseapp.com/sockjs-node/525/zl4etbam/websocket'

Likely you're trying to use the Firebase Database, in which case you've mistyped the URL. It should be `https://test-1d6f7.firebaseio.com` (note `firebaseio` instead of `firebaseapp`).

Comment: Something in your app is trying to open a socket to the `/test-1d6f7.firebaseapp.com`. That is not a valid connection, since Firebase Hosting doesn't take incoming websocket connections like that. Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the above is my best guess as to the cause.